# Find which JKS through code

Tags: java, maven, security, keystore

I think its a basic question but I could not find anything regarding it on the internet.

I am writing a small webservice in a monolithic application. I wanna programmatically find out which Java Key Store is being used.

Inside my pom file I can see something like this:

```
<artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.16</version>
<configuration>
    <systemProperties>
        <property>
            <name>javax.net.ssl.trustStore</name>
            <value>keystore/kc.jks</value>
        </property>
</configuration>
```

Now is the Keystore mentioned in pom file being used or the internal Java one.

NOTE: I want to write some Code to find which keystore rather than just checking some configurations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The systemProperties setting in your pom file only applies to your tests, and only applies if you also configure surefire to fork, which you haven't. So it's having no effect. If you set surefire to fork, so that system properties would take effect, you could see the setting with:

```
System.getProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore")
```

Comment: This always returns null for me. I have tried it many times. What can be the reason for it. How can I load the one from pom file. I thought setting stuff in pom file would put it globally.

Comment: the fork does not work with surefire. I am very curios why it does not work

Comment: Thanks this actually solve my problem. Also it was cool to know that I can set up properties via code and dont have to provide it everytime i run using maven